# How to stop segue from automatically unwind

Tags: ios, segue

I am working on an app on xcode Version 6.2, it is quite a simple app. You can register and login for now however whenever i try to login with the correct username and password it loads the "protected" page the automatically sends me back to login page showing me this error code:"2015-10-25 23:22:48.254 Test[46561:6996119] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!". When i stop building the app and then build it loads the "protected" page and i am signed in and can logout.

I am quite  new to xcode and i followed a tutorial on Youtube then tried to modify it.

I am using Parse to store data if that is to any help..

I can provide the view of the different views and code

Comment: Can you show me the code where you perform the login step? Also as a side note, please edit your original question to add extra info, instead of posting them as an answer! :)

Comment: i fixed the issue but thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to debug without any further info, but my guess is that you are likely trying to present a view controller whose views you are adding into the `UIAlertView` that pops out that notifies whether your login is successful. So for example, if you are trying to add some views into the `UIAlertView` after it has been dismissed, this error will show up.

If that is the case, use `presentViewController:animated:completion` in your login view controller to present the secret page instead.

If that doesn't help, please post the code regarding your login completion block from Parse.

Comment: I tried it and it did not work, i got this error instead: 2015-10-26 08:38:33.139 Test[47354:7023476] Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7ff9c064aad0> on <Test.signInPage: 0x7ff9c0486c20> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!. How do i find my completion block on Parse?

Comment: [EDIT]I fixed the issue now but before i login the initial loading page is presented before "protected" page, it is something with my hierachy.

Answer (score 0):

[My view hierachy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG8ck.png)

When i login(purple page), the initial page(green page) is presented before  "protected"(red page) is loaded.